# IICS taskflow - Notification task - attach file

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I have an IICS taskflow with a mapping task and a notification task. The target of the mapping task is a csv stored in a server location.

With the notification task, I want to send an email with the csv attached. Do you know if this is possible or if is there another way to get to send the target csv by email??

Comment: What is the size of the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Not the ideal solution, but you can write a simple python program to send the csv as an email, just provide the path of the csv to python program. and then, execute the python script from informatica as a command task. (IF Success) it is super easy to use a python script.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import os
import shutil


def send_mail(body_text, fromaddr, recipient_list, smtp_login, smtp_pass, file_path):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(recipient_list)
    msg['Subject'] = 'your Subject variable'
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body_text, 'plain'))

    filename = os.path.basename(file_path)
    attachment = open(file_path, "rb")

    part = MIMEBase('multipart', 'mixed; name=%s' % filename)
    part.set_payload(attachment.read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

    msg.attach(part)

    server = smtplib.SMTP(host="your.mailserver.com", port=123)
    # eg smtp.google.com

    server.starttls()
    server.login(smtp_login, smtp_pass)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, recipient_list, text)
    server.quit()


mainDir = '/path/to/file'

sendFileName = 'yourfilename' + '.csv'
sourceFilePath = mainDir + 'file_send/filename.csv'


body_text = '''
Dear All,

Please find attached document

Thank You.

'''



smtp_login = "emailusername"
smtp_pass = "emaipassword"
recipient_list = ['abc@company.com', 'def@company.com']
file_path = os.path.abspath(sendFilePath)

fromaddr = 'emailusername@company.com'

send_mail(body_text=body_text, fromaddr=fromaddr, recipient_list=recipient_list, smtp_login=smtp_login, smtp_pass=smtp_pass,
          file_path=file_path)
```

This code may needs some modifications but thought it might help someone.